# Is it possible to use lxml extension functions in xpath predicates in xslt stylesheet?

Tags: python, xslt, xpath, lxml

An extension function works in xpath evaluation, but not in xslt transform. Is such use not supported at all or do I miss something?

```
root = etree.XML('<a><b class="true">Haegar</b><b class="false">Baegar</b></a>')
doc = etree.ElementTree(root)

def match_class(context, arg):
    return 'class' in context.context_node.attrib and context.context_node.attrib['class'] == arg

ns = etree.FunctionNamespace('http://example.com/myother/functions')
ns.prefix = 'css'
ns['class'] = match_class

result = root.xpath("//*[css:class('true')]")
assert result[0].text == "Haegar"

xslt = etree.XSLT(etree.XML('''
   <stylesheet version="1.0"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          xmlns:css="http://example.com/functions">
     <output method="text" encoding="ASCII"/>
     <template match="/">
        <apply-templates select="//*[css:class('true')]"/>
     </template>
   </stylesheet>
'''))

result = xslt(doc)
assert str(result) == "Haegar"
```

The first assert passes.

But the call to `xslt(doc)` resuts in `lxml.etree.XSLTApplyError: Failed to evaluate the 'select' expression.`, or `lxml.etree.XSLTApplyError: Error applying stylesheet` if to put the xpath into some template match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use the wrong namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:es="http://example.com/functions"
```

You should change in:

```
xmlns:css="http://example.com/myother/functions"
```

**EDIT**

The following example works perfectly:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.XML(u'<a><b class="true">Haegar</b><b class="false">Baegar</b></a>')
doc = etree.ElementTree(root)


def match_class(context, arg):
    return 'class' in context.context_node.attrib and context.context_node.attrib['class'] == arg


ns = etree.FunctionNamespace('http://example.com/myother/functions')
ns.prefix = 'css'
ns['class'] = match_class

result = root.xpath("//*[css:class('true')]")
assert result[0].text == "Haegar"

xslt = etree.XSLT(etree.XML(u'''\
   <stylesheet version="1.0"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          xmlns:css="http://example.com/myother/functions">
     <output method="text" encoding="ASCII"/>
     <template match="/">
        <apply-templates select="//*[css:class('true')]"/>
     </template>
   </stylesheet>
'''))

result = xslt(doc)
assert str(result) == "Haegar"
```

Tested with Python 2.7 and lxml == 3.8.0

Comment: yep. fixed that.
but it does't help.

Comment: @qMax: But it does work with `xmlns:css="http://example.com/myother/functions"`. You did not add `myother/` in the question, you only changed `es` to `css`.

Comment: Oh, my bad!

Thanks for help!